# Sort nested object by date in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

How can i sort the data by date and find maximum value count between consecutive dates ? Example data:

```js
const data = {
    'addias':{
        '2022-1-10': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
        '2022-1-09': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
        '2021-12-29': ['a'],
        '2021-12-28': ['y', 'u', 'v', 'd', 'f', 'f', 'g'],
        '2021-1-08': ['x', 't', 's', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    },
    'nike':{
        '2022-1-20': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
        '2022-1-15': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        '2022-1-14': ['a', 'b'],
        '2022-1-10': ['y', 'b', 'x', 'z', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    }
}
```

result be like

```js
const result = {
     'addias':{
        'firstDate': '2022-1-09',
        'secondDate':'2022-1-10',
        'total':14 ,
    },
    'nike':{
        'firstDate': '2022-1-14',
        'secondDate':'2022-1-15',
        'total':5,
    }
}
```

Attempt:

```js
Object.entries(data).forEach((item) => {
   const [ brand, dates ] = item; /** {'2022-1-10': array } */
   let sorted = Object.entries(dates).sort((a,b) => new Date(a[0]) - new Date(b[0]))
   /** find value count for each sorted date */
   
   /** find if the dates are consecutive */

   /** build new object with result property */ 

})
```

Comment: How does your attempt relate to what you want done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think finding out the date pairs before counting would be more efficient, I think this should solve the problem:

```js
const data = {
  'addias': {
    '2022-1-10': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    '2022-1-09': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    '2021-12-29': ['a'],
    '2021-12-28': ['y', 'u', 'v', 'd', 'f', 'f', 'g'],
    '2021-1-08': ['x', 't', 's', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
  },
  'nike': {
    '2022-1-20': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    '2022-1-15': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    '2022-1-14': ['a', 'b'],
    '2022-1-10': ['y', 'b', 'x', 'z', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
  }
};

function maxValueBetweenConsecutiveDates(input) {
  const result = {};
  for (const brand in input) {
    const dates = Object
      .keys(input[brand])
      .map(e => ({
        date: new Date(e),
        original: e
      }))
      .sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);

    const pairs = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < dates.length; i++) {
      if (dates[i].date - dates[i - 1].date === 86400000) {
        pairs.push([dates[i - 1], dates[i]]);
      }
    }

    const quantities = pairs.map(pair => ({
      firstDate: pair[0].original,
      secondDate: pair[1].original,
      total: input[brand][pair[0].original].length + input[brand][pair[1].original].length
    }));
    const max = Math.max(...quantities.map(e => e.total));
    const quantity = quantities.find(e => e.total === max);

    result[brand] = quantity;
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(maxValueBetweenConsecutiveDates(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, altough you might want to write a custom sorting function

```js
const data = {
    'addias':{
        '2022-1-10': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
        '2022-1-09': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
        '2021-12-29': ['a'],
        '2021-12-28': ['y', 'u', 'v', 'd', 'f', 'f', 'g'],
        '2021-1-08': ['x', 't', 's', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    },
    'nike':{
        '2022-1-20': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
        '2022-1-15': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        '2022-1-14': ['a', 'b'],
        '2022-1-10': ['y', 'b', 'x', 'z', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    }
}

const result = {};

Object.keys(data).forEach(sneaker => {
  const dates = Object.keys(data[sneaker]);
  dates.sort();
  result[sneaker] = {
    firstDate: dates[0],
    secondDate: dates[1],
    total: dates.length
  };
});

console.log(result);
```